# Linux file folder Permission issue (Owned by group)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, permissions, user-accounts

I have created three users:
- media, media1 and media2
I have added these users to group called Media.

than using chgrp i have modified group on two existing folders "Archive" and "Media".

Media group should have read/write/modify access to these two directories and sub directories.

at moment all directories are owned by Media group.

Directory is as follow :

```
# ls -ld
drwxrwsr-x    2 media1 Media 4096 Jul 26 12:22 Media/
```

but when user media2 tries to remove this directory or file or tries to create new file/folder under Archive or Media folder it throws error permission denied.

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the "write" permission for the group.

```
chmod g+w Media/
chmod g+w Archive/
```

Should solve your problem.

For further information, see [This tutorial](http://www.unix.com/tips-tutorials/19060-unix-file-permissions.html)

Comment: i have deleted the old one. because it was closed (duplicate) and added detailed info into this.

Comment: Then that's okay I guess. Happy to have helped you.

Comment: drwxrwsr-x 2 media1 Media 4096 Jul 26 08:12 but user media2 error: Unable to create folder Permission denied.

Comment: @UsmanMasood I guess media2 is correctly in Media group ? (does `groups` tell so ?)

Comment: media1 : media-daemon Media
media2 : Share Media

both users belong to Media group. result of groups command.

Comment: I have tried to setup the exact same setup on my computer and i am able to create/delete files under `Media/` owned by `media1` user and `media`group, mode rwxrwsr-x with `media2` user. 
This work both when users have media as primary or additional group

Comment: my current directory permissions are:
drwxrwsr-x 2 media1 Media 4096 Jul 26 08:12
Any difference in that?

Comment: Mine is absolutely identical. : drwxrwsr-x    2 media1   Media        4096 Jul 26 14:55 Media    ///    
user media1 : uid=3034(media1) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),3034(Media)    ////    
user media2 : uid=3035(media2) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),3034(Media)

Comment: Can you update your question with traces from what your are trying that fails ?

Comment: not sure, if that resolved it. a Chown to group did the trick. anyhow thanks for help.